# Why am I getting a Vercel deployment Next.js route error?

Tags: next.js, prisma, vercel

I am attempting to deploy my Next13 app on Vercel but I am receiving this error and I can't find out what the issue is referring to.

```
Type error: Route "app/api/signup/route.js" does not match the required types of a Next.js Route.
  "prisma" is not a valid Route export field.
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

What could this mean?

Comment: Can you show `app/api/signup/route.js`?

Answer (score 1):

App Router only allows [HTTP methods](https://nextjs.org//docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route#http-methods) and [Route Segment Config](https://nextjs.org//docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config) in `route.ts/js` files.

Event before deploying to Vercel, `npm run build` should also show you this error

Unfortunately, you simply cannot export a custom key like `export const prisma = ...`
The only solution is to do that in a separate file, and import/export what you need from there

---

I actually started a discussion/PR that allows this. If that's still a pain point for you, maybe you can have a look and upvote it.

- Discussion: [#55140 (Allow custom Route export field)](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/55140)
- PR Draft: [#55157 (Allows custom route.ts exports with the "_" prefix)](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/55157)